# Flip animation to disable button

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

I am working on a simple animated UI that should change the buttons from enabled to disabled. But rather than simply changing the color from red to grey I would like the button to flip.

I've tried simple animation on click of the button but all I can do is to rotate the button.

Any help how to create a flip animation?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I've created simple R.anim.test_rotate with <rotate/> element and starting it with `button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.test_rotate));`

Comment: @Mazmat did you solve your problem..?if not tried posted answer by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flipping Animation:

```
<set android:ordering="sequentially">
<objectAnimator android:duration="2000" 
android:propertyName="rotationY"
android:valueFrom="0" 
android:valueTo="360">
</objectAnimator>
</set>
```

In Class:

```
AnimatorSet set;
set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.flipping);
set.setTarget(img_logo);
set.start();

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 2000);
```

Comment: objectAnimator is not a valid in R.anim

Comment: I have used this in my app which is live on play store and working fine.

Comment: Actually it is working. But I had to put it into R.animator and create it with AnimatorInflator.

Comment: check my updated code. I think you are talking about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

test_rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="250" />
```